# Maximo Anywhere - Hide or disable list view record

Tags: javascript, maximo-anywhere

I am calling an eventHandler on a "list" view control in app.xml on render event. I want to hide or disable the record from "list" view depending upon flag value.

```
 <list displayPageSize="5" id="WorkExecution.WorkItemsView_workOrder_list" queryBase="getMyAssignedWork" recordLabel="Work Order {0}" resolverClass="application.handlers.WOListHandler" resolverFunction="resolveWonumLabel" resource="workOrder" transitionTo="WorkExecution.WorkDetailView"  >
......... </list>
```

How to hide or disable the record from "list" view?

Comment: Maybe you can help us help you better by providing more context to your problem. You asked what is the "correct way", does that mean it's working now but could be done better?

Comment: Sorry, I'm updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a 'render' eventHandler in the listItemTemplate block instead of the list block. When it triggers you can do

```
if(eventContext.currentRecord.wonum === '1106'){
    eventContext.baseWidget.domNode.style.display = 'none';
}
```

The above condition looks for wonum 1106 and hides the list item. To disable the entire list item requires some extra work; depending on what you want e.g Stop transition or display a message on click etc..